# How to run a docker containter linked to a previously created volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a named volume with stuff in it.
I would like to provide this volume as I provide a path: `docker run -v /host:/path.in.docker.container` - this works for paths. I'd like to do the same with a volume I manually created and filled.

I know about --volumes-from, but how do i first connect the volume to the empty container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a volume thanks to `docker create`, [see the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/), then, mount this volume-container with the option `--volume` of the command `docker run` as in `docker run -v volumename:/data -it my_image`.

Comment: isn't `--link` for other containers (from help: "Add link to another container")?

Comment: Yes, `--link` is for containers, but a volume is a container too.

Comment: `docker: Error response from daemon: Could not get container for my_vol`. Also I can't seem to find any documentation ot the subject.

Comment: [Did you](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/) [find out](http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/) [these](http://container42.com/2014/11/18/data-only-container-madness/) [links](http://container42.com/2014/11/03/docker-indepth-volumes/)?

Comment: `-v volumename:/data` this was the part I was missing - reusing a volume. I don't understand why would any one use a data-only container where the data is in a volume. Anyway I apologize for being the proverbial lazy guy.

Comment: No problem, if you found what you were looking for then it's great!

Comment: Can you put this in an answer, so I can tag it as correct

Comment: `--link` is for containers, not volumes. `-v volumename:/data` is what works. That's what I meant.